# Javascript Function Self Invoking Inside Object

Tags: javascript

Instead using setInterval i can use this, to repeatly call an function.

```
function foo(){
    setTimeout(foo, 1000);
}();
```

The problem is, i want to do the same thing, inside an `object`, here the snippet.

```
var evt;
var init;

evt = function() {
    return {
        cycle:function(str) {
            setTimeout(function(str) {
                this.cycle(str);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}

init = new evt();
init.cycle("Hallo word");
```

Then the error shows up, it said

> this.cycle() is not a function.

I'm trying to make an variable as `this` at the above line of my codes, here, like this

```
var evt;
var init;

evt = function() {
    var parent;

    parent = this;
    return {
        cycle:function(str) {
            setTimeout(function(str) {
                parent.cycle(str);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}

init = new evt();
init.cycle("Hallo word");
```

But still getting.

> parent.cycle() is not a function

Is there a way to do this, what i want here is, went i call `evt.cycle("Hello World")` after first attempt showing `Hello World` it will repeatly showing `Hello World` in every next seconds.

I need to keep the function inside the object that generated by that function. Thanks for any correction.

Comment: To do this without using any additional language features (though you should really check out classes and/or lambdas), you can create the object using `a = {}` and then assign `a.cycle = function()`, using `a` instead of `this` inside

Comment: Why does your `evt` constructor return an unrelated object? Why doesn't it just use `this` (which is the newly created object (created by `new`))?

Comment: Wrong `this`. Try:
`cycle:function(str) {
          let _this = this;
            setTimeout(function(str) {
                _this.cycle(str);
                console.log('Hi')
            }, 1000);
        }`

Comment: Ok, I do not what are you trying to achieve here, but taking your first example... you just need to add .bind(this) to your anonymous function inside the setTimeout... it will be like this `setTimeout(function(str){ ... }.bind(this), 1000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a new object a new scope is defined. So you should bind this pointer to the function. Or you can use .bind(this) function in this way:

```
setTimeout((function(str){ 
}).bind(this), 1000)
```

For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Or you can use call or apply: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

In es6 you could use ()=>{} (arrow) function, when the this pointer is inherited.

Other working solution:

```js
var evt;
var init;

evt = function() {
    var parent;

    parent = this;
    return {
        cycle:function(str) {
            var me = this;
            setTimeout(function(str) {
                console.log("cycle");
                me.cycle(str);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}

init = new evt();
init.cycle("Hallo word");
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```js
const evt = function() {
  return {
    i: 0,
    cycle: function(str) {
      const _this = this;
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(str.substring(0, this.i));
        _this.cycle(str, ++this.i);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
}

init = new evt();
init.cycle("Hello world");
```

I extended the example a little bit to illustrate the effect of `this` a little more.